# How much disk space I need for Win10/Kali dual boot?

Tags: partition, windows, kali-linux, dual-boot

So, I recently got a new laptop with a 256 SSD and I want to dual boot Win10 and Linux Kali on it. How much space do Kali and Windows need? Just the operating systems after installation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *kali-2016.1* install was pretty complete and has a lot of stuff.  I allocated a 50Gb VM disk to it:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        48G   19G   27G  42% /
```

(That also includes a 4Gb Nessus install I added afterwards, and 4Gb of apt caches from a `dist-upgrade`).

I have a mini-laptop with 32Gb SSD running Windows 10.  It can be *tight* when receiving larger Windows 10 updates (I had to use a USB drive for one update; it was too large).  I would recommend minimum 50Gb, probably 100Gb for Windows 10, especially if you plan on adding software (Office?) or games.

Comment: Then as a "guess", 50Gb for Kali and 200Gb for Windows may work :-)  Depends on how big your school programs end up being.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forums.
I got the system-requiments from official sites.
Windows 10 need at least 16GB for 32 bit OS and 20GB for 64bit.
Kali Linux (2.0) need at least 10GB (maybe for both 64bit and 32bit?). #fixme

Comment: Yes,but you need a partition for installed packages. (both for Linux and for Windows). I did the same, installed the Kali on 9.0GB ext4 partition, and it's always warn me with low disk space. /and I still ignore/ :D